# How to avoid autoselect when textbox has focus in windows phone sdk 7.1?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

Let's say I have a textbox with number 123.456 (InputScope="Number")

When It gets focus, after I tapped it, 456 is autoselected.

I can't see any property to cancel this. Is there any hidden way ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on WP8. I've got a textbox with `Number` as the input scope. When I tap it, the keyboard comes up and the cursor is at a particular position (depending on where I tapped it) but no part of the number is actually selected. Do you mean tapping it *after* it has focus? If so, do you just want to prevent the user from selecting any part of the text?

Comment: You're right I rather meant tapping after focus. I want the user to be able to move the cursor inside (I want to do some increment depending on cursor position).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply deselect everything whenever a selection is made by handling the `SelectionChanged` event. For example

```
private void myTextbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //get the position the user clicked
    int start = myTextbox.SelectionStart;

    //detach this event handler so it's not fired when we clear the selection
    myTextbox.SelectionChanged -= myTextbox_SelectionChanged;

    //clear the selection but keep the cursor in the place it would've been
    myTextbox.Select(start, 0);

    //reattach the handler
    myTextbox.SelectionChanged += myTextbox_SelectionChanged;
}
```

This should prevent any text from being selected. To get the actual position the user tapped within the textbox, you can handle the `Tap` event and use the `GetPosition()` method of the `GestureEventArgs` parameter that is passed.